# scatter3 of an image shows me a complete white plot

Tags: plot, scatter

I want to scatter plot an RGB image to show the correlation between its colours.

This is my code

```
I = imread('TestImage_small.png');
[h, w, ~] = size(I);

B = (I(:,:,3));
G = (I(:,:,2));
R = (I(:,:,1));
RGB = [reshape(R,1,h*w); reshape(G,1,h*w); reshape(B,1,h*w)];


figure;
scatter3(R(:),G(:),B(:),[], (RGB'),'filled');
view(40,35)
```

It draws the image plot , but without any colour , only white!

any help please !

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You have to divide by 255. In order for the colors to work; they have to be between 0 and 1.

Try this:

```
scatter3(r(:),g(:),b(:),[], (RGB')/255,'filled');
```